# How to handle prepareForSegue from another NavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue, handle

I call performSegueWithIdentifier like that based on design reason.

```
- (void)showViewWithSegueIdentifier:(NSString *)segueIdentifier {

    [self.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];

}
```

when I try to handle prepareForSegue method, it is still not called.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

  NSLog(@"Call");

}
```

Is it possible to handle prepareForSegue from another controller?

Comment: Does the view perform the segue?  Or does that not get called either?

Comment: it is called, but method prepareForSegue still not working.

Comment: The class where you are logging @"Call" MainViewController?

Comment: I created storyboard with a few NavigationController with Container View.
MainViewController has a show (e.g. Push) segue to other view (viewForm).
From other MainMenuViewController I call performSegueWithIdentifier which works how I wanted. But method prepareForSegue in MainMenuViewController not working. I think because this segue not exist in this MainMenuViewController. I'm looking any ways how it can be fixed.

Comment: @mike You had the log I suggested in an answer you provided, but it didn't make its way back up into your question. If memory serves me correctly self.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController was actually MainViewController and not MainMenuViewController as you expected and likely the issue. Am I correct or was it MainMenuViewController that was logged out?

Comment: I have NavigationController > MainViewController wich has Container View.
Conteiner View has > NavigationController > MenuViewController.
Inside this container I'm embed menu with buttons. I had to do this way, based on design requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do what you want, although most of the time it is not a good idea. However, you may have a good reason.

To figure out why it isn't work I would look at what self.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController really is. If it is nil nothing will happen and it won't crash. Guessing your navigation controller doesn't have a navigation controller.

try

```
UIViewController *viewController = self.navigationController.navigationController.topViewController;
NSLog(@"This is my view controller: %@", viewController);

[viewController performSegueWithIdentifier:segueIdentifier sender:self];
```

and see if there is actually a viewController.

**Edit:**

If it is not nil there is also a chance that topViewController would return the UIViewController that called it. You could add this log right under the "This is my view controller" log and see if it is the same as above.

```
NSLog(@"This called prepareForSegue: %@", self);
```

The thing that doesn't add up though is you didn't mention the app crashing, you just said it didn't work. Meaning that whatever you are calling prepareForSegue on must have the same segue identifier. I believe view controllers get really mad if you call a segue that isn't there and crash the app at least that is what I remember. However, it has been a while sense I did that and could be wrong.

One last thing I would look at is the viewDidLoad: of the controller you expect to perform the segue and log it out and see if it matches the "This is my view controller" log.

I hope that helps and good luck. =)

Comment: Check out my answer on your question. Do you have any idea how it can be realize?

Comment: I added a comment to your question. You also might want to consider removing your answer and adding that to your question. This makes it easier for others to understand what you have tried.